# Scoutsuite output is showing IAM api is not enabled when it is enabled in gcp console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

After Running the Scoutsuite for GCP project using service-account, the output is showing IAM API is not enabled, when the Identity and Access Management (IAM) API, IAM Service Account Credentials API both are enabled in GCP Console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you read the last message in your screenshot, notice **Failed to retrieve KMS key rings: 400 Billing is disabled for project XXX.**

You either have a payment problem or you have not assigned this project to a billing account.

Comment: If the project is assigned to a billing account still it shows IAM API is not enabled. I have tried with multiple accounts.